# Workflow starts slowly

Tags: workflow, performance, workflow-activity

I have developed 2 workflows. Both are run manually. The first workflow starts the second, waits for it to finish, and then carries on. There are no problems really, it's just that once the second workflow is started, it is in `Starting` state for around 5 minutes and then it finally kicks off. When I checked the details, it said that the workflow is in `Starting` state due to the heavy load of the machine. I don't believe that this is the actual case because my machine has 8GB of RAM and it's an isolated development machine and I am the only user accessing SharePoint.

Is there any way to improve the performance through code? Should I pay attention to something that might be the cause of this behavior, other than resources leaking (which I checked already)? Thanks.

Comment: What type of activities do you have in the second workflow? do you have any wait, pause, or task processes

Comment: The second workflow is making workflow tasks and updates the workflow item properties based on the task completion. But second workflow activities are completely unrelated to my problem as they happen after the workflow is started. I am concerned about the time it takes to start the second workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SharePoint is under load or thinks that your workflow is heavy then it'll send it to be processed in the backgound using the workflow timer job, which by default run every 5 minutes.

For more information see [How to Improve Workflow Performance in SharePoint Server 2010](http://melick-rajee.blogspot.dk/2011/09/how-to-improve-workflow-performance-in.html) and [Estimate performance and capacity planning for workflow in SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508755.aspx)

But expect your workflows to have this behaviour in production. This is by design.